# Social authentication in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, social-authentication

I am trying to authenticate using social authentication in laravel. I have this code in services.php

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => 'your-facebook-id',
        'client_secret' => 'your-facebook-app-secret',
        'redirect' => 'http://your-callback-url',
        ],
```

And whenever i try to login the facebook shows:

> Invalid App ID: your-facebook-id

What actually are `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `redirect` here?

I have these methods for redirecting the user to the OAuth provider, and another for receiving the callback from the provider after authentication.

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
     return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
     $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
     dd($user->getEmail);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Socialite?

Comment: Check this url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes. i am using Socialite

Comment: Okay so have you set your facebook app up that receives the request? The `client_id` and `secret` is the information linked to the app you set up inside Facebook

Comment: @Steve I see your edit but have you actually made an app on facebook to accept the connection?

Comment: you have to first create facebook developer app,in here you can found client_id and secret.To do this you can follow my blog http://www.kingpabel.com/create-facebook-developer-app-7-easy-steps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `client_id` and the `client_secret` from Facebook when you create an "app" in their system (In this context an app isn't what you might think initially).

https://developers.facebook.com/

Once created, your `client_id` will be what they call "App ID" and your `client_secret` will be what they call "App Secret". You need to click the "Show" button and re-authenticate to get hold of your secret.

Your `redirect` is where you want Facebook to redirect you after the user has authorised your app. Generally this redirect should be where you're actually handling the login process, which in your case is the URL/route that passes control to your `handleProviderCallback()` method.